# Color according to condition.

Tags: plotting, color, list-manipulation

So, my problem is the following: I have the following table

```
tableresults = Table[{x, y, If[xpto < 0, -1, 
               If[xpto > 0, 1, 0]]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.001}, {y, 0, 1, 0.001}]
```

Where "xpto" is a function of x and y. So, now I want to plot the points {x,y} according to a color defined by the third value. This would mean that every point would be either, for instance, red if 1, blue if -1, and black if 0. The problem is that I have no idea how to do it. I try to explore the function ColorFunction, but this didn't produce the results wanted. Anyone can help?

Comment: Have you seen `ArrayPlot`'s option `ColorRules`?  (You can also use the option `DataRange` to adjust the axes ranges, if desired.)

Comment: Did you know there's a `Sign[]` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have your xpto function, so I'll use a random choice,

```
tableresults = 
  Table[{x, y, RandomChoice[{-1, 0, 1}]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.01}, {y, 0, 1, 
    0.01}];
```

You can get what you are looking for via `ListPlot`

```
ListPlot[
 Style[{#1, #2}, #3 /. {-1 -> Blue, 0 -> Black, 1 -> Red}] & @@@ 
  Flatten[tableresults, 1]]
```

[image]

or `ListDensityPlot`

```
ListDensityPlot[Flatten[tableresults, 1], 
 ColorFunction -> (Which[# == -1, Blue, # == 0, Black, # == 1, 
     Red] &), InterpolationOrder -> 0, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

or `MatrixPlot`

```
MatrixPlot[tableresults[[All, All, 3]], 
 ColorRules -> {-1 -> Blue, 0 -> Black, 1 -> Red}, 
 DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
xpto[x_, y_] := Sign[x + y - 1]
DensityPlot[xpto[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Blue, Red}, #] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]