# Rewrite ListPlot using Graphics while perserving point color?

Tags: plotting, graphics, color, conditional, style

I have a lot of data points, and I have noticed that plotting using Graphics is usually much quicker than plotting with ListPlot. The problem is I am trying to color the data points based off some conditions, so for ListPlot, what I have written to do this is:

```
coloredData = Style[{#1, #2}, {#3, #6} /. {{0, 0} -> Gray, {0, 1} -> Black, {1, 0} -> Red}] & @@@ Partition[Flatten@data, 6]
ListPlot[coloredData]
```

[image]

Now, without the Style, if I were plotting my data using Graphics, I do:

```
dPlot = Table[Point[data[[i, All, {1, 2}]]], {i, Length@data}];
```

[image]

So I wanted to do the same thing with `coloredData`, and wrote:

```
cPlot = Table[Point[Partition[coloredData, 20][[i, All, {1, 2}]]], {i, Length@Partition[coloredData, 20]}];
```

[image]

From the error message it seems that now the data is in the wrong format for plotting using Graphics.

So my question is this: how do I rewrite what I currently plot using ListPlot, but with Graphics? When I try looking up phrases such as "coloring points according to conditions" I'm finding results like [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108976/color-according-to-condition) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99818/listplot-conditional-coloring-of-plotpoints) which use ListPlot, and for computational time concerns, I'd like to use Graphics instead. Any advice for how to tackle this, would be much appreciated!

Here is some of my data:

```
data = {{{20, 6.48815, 1, 0.876608, 0.5, 0}, {20, 6.47738, 0, 0.521964, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.97118, 0, 0.0862234, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.15164, 0, 0.377913,0.5, 0}, {20, 6.43098, 0, 0.0116446, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.88699, 1, 0.927266, 0.5, 0}, {20, 3.10361, 0, 0.543757, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.96474, 1, 0.479332, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.86771, 0, 0.245349, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.12694, 1, 0.759896, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.70262, 1, 0.984993, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.54488, 1, 0.217045, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.75599, 1, 0.459017, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.24446, 1, 0.884729, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.81927, 1, 0.583854, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.45835, 0, 0.263973, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.80958, 1, 0.91956, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.96297, 1, 0.423835, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.2311, 1, 0.98729, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.76275, 1, 0.587943, 0.5, 0}}, {{20, 6.48815, 1, 0.876608, 0.5, 0}, {20, 6.47738, 0, 0.521964, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.97118, 0, 0.0862234, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.15164, 0, 0.377913, 0.5, 0}, {20, 6.43098, 0, 0.0116446,0.5, 0}, {20, 7.88699, 1, 0.927266, 0.5, 0}, {20, 3.10361, 0, 0.543757, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.96474, 1, 0.479332, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.86771, 0, 0.245349, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.12694, 1, 0.759896, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.70262, 1, 0.984993, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.54488, 1, 0.217045, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.75599, 1, 0.459017, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.24446, 1, 0.884729, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.81927, 1, 0.583854, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.45835, 0, 0.263973, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.80958, 1, 0.91956, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.96297, 1, 0.423835, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.2311, 1, 0.98729, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.76275, 1, 0.587943, 0.5, 0}}, {{20, 6.48815, 1, 0.876608, 0.5, 0}, {20, 6.47738, 0, 0.521964, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.97118, 0, 0.0862234, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.15164, 0, 0.377913, 0.5, 0}, {20, 6.43098, 0, 0.0116446, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.88699, 1, 0.927266,0.5, 0}, {20, 3.10361, 0, 0.543757, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.96474, 1, 0.479332, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.86771, 0, 0.245349, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.12694, 1, 0.759896, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.70262, 1, 0.984993, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.54488, 1, 0.217045, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.75599, 1, 0.459017, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.24446, 1, 0.884729, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.81927, 1, 0.583854, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.45835, 0, 0.263973, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.80958, 1, 0.91956, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.96297, 1, 0.423835, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.2311, 1, 0.98729, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.76275, 1, 0.587943, 0.5, 0}}, {{20, 6.48815, 1, 0.876608, 0.5, 0}, {20, 6.47738, 0, 0.521964, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.97118, 0, 0.0862234, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.15164, 0, 0.377913, 0.5, 0}, {20, 6.43098, 0, 0.0116446, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.88699, 1, 0.927266, 0.5, 0}, {20, 3.10361, 0, 0.543757, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.96474, 1, 0.479332, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.86771, 0, 0.245349, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.12694, 1, 0.759896, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.70262, 1, 0.984993, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.54488, 1, 0.217045, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.75599, 1, 0.459017, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.24446, 1, 0.884729, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.81927, 1, 0.583854, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.45835, 0, 0.263973, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.80958, 1, 0.91956, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.96297,1, 0.423835, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.2311, 1, 0.98729, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.76275, 1, 0.587943, 0.5, 0}}, {{20, 6.48815, 1, 0.876608, 0.5, 0}, {20, 6.47738, 0, 0.521964, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.97118, 0, 0.0862234,0.5, 0}, {20, 2.15164, 0, 0.377913, 0.5, 0}, {20, 6.43098, 0, 0.0116446, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.88699, 1, 0.927266, 0.5, 0}, {20, 3.10361, 0, 0.543757, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.96474, 1, 0.479332, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.86771, 0, 0.245349, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.12694, 1, 0.759896, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.70262, 1, 0.984993, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.54488, 1, 0.217045, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.75599, 1, 0.459017, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.24446, 1, 0.884729, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.81927, 1, 0.583854, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.45835, 0, 0.263973, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.80958, 1, 0.91956, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.96297, 1, 0.423835, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.2311, 1, 0.98729, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.76275, 1, 0.587943, 0.5, 0}}, {{20, 6.48815, 1, 0.876608, 0.5, 0}, {20, 6.47738, 0, 0.521964, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.97118, 0, 0.0862234, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.15164, 0, 0.377913,0.5, 0}, {20, 6.43098, 0, 0.0116446, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.88699, 1, 0.927266, 0.5, 0}, {20, 3.10361, 0, 0.543757, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.96474, 1, 0.479332, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.86771, 0, 0.245349, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.12694, 1, 0.759896, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.70262, 1, 0.984993, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.54488, 1, 0.217045, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.75599, 1, 0.459017, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.24446, 1, 0.884729, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.81927, 1, 0.583854, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.45835, 0, 0.263973, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.80958, 1, 0.91956, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.96297, 1, 0.423835, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.2311, 1, 0.98729, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.76275, 1, 0.587943, 0.5, 0}}, {{20, 6.48815, 1, 0.876608, 0.5, 0}, {20, 6.47738, 0, 0.521964, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.97118, 0, 0.0862234, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.15164, 0, 0.377913, 0.5, 0}, {20, 6.43098, 0, 0.0116446,0.5, 0}, {20, 7.88699, 1, 0.927266, 0.5, 0}, {20, 3.10361, 0, 0.543757, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.96474, 1, 0.479332, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.86771, 0, 0.245349, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.12694, 1, 0.759896, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.70262, 1, 0.984993, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.54488, 1, 0.217045, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.75599, 1, 0.459017, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.24446, 1, 0.884729, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.81927, 1, 0.583854, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.45835, 0, 0.263973, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.80958, 1, 0.91956, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.96297, 1, 0.423835, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.2311, 1, 0.98729, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.76275, 1, 0.587943, 0.5, 0}}, {{20, 6.48815, 1, 0.876608, 0.5, 0}, {20, 6.47738, 0, 0.521964, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.97118, 0, 0.0862234, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.15164, 0, 0.377913, 0.5, 0}, {20, 6.43098, 0, 0.0116446, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.88699, 1, 0.927266,0.5, 0}, {20, 3.10361, 0, 0.543757, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.96474, 1, 0.479332, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.86771, 0, 0.245349, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.12694, 1, 0.759896, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.70262, 1, 0.984993, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.54488, 1, 0.217045, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.75599, 1, 0.459017, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.24446, 1, 0.884729, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.81927, 1, 0.583854, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.45835, 0, 0.263973, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.80958, 1, 0.91956, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.96297, 1, 0.423835, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.2311, 1, 0.98729, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.76275, 1, 0.587943, 0.5, 0}}, {{20, 6.48815, 1, 0.876608, 0.5, 0}, {20, 6.47738, 0, 0.521964, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.97118, 0, 0.0862234, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.15164, 0, 0.377913, 0.5, 0}, {20, 6.43098, 0, 0.0116446, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.88699, 1, 0.927266, 0.5, 0}, {20, 3.10361, 0, 0.543757, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.96474, 1, 0.479332, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.86771, 0, 0.245349, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.12694, 1, 0.759896, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.70262, 1, 0.984993, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.54488, 1, 0.217045, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.75599, 1, 0.459017, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.24446, 1, 0.884729, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.81927, 1, 0.583854, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.45835, 0, 0.263973, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.80958, 1, 0.91956, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.96297,1, 0.423835, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.2311, 1, 0.98729, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.76275, 1, 0.587943, 0.5, 0}}, {{20, 6.48815, 1, 0.876608, 0.5, 0}, {20, 6.47738, 0, 0.521964, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.97118, 0, 0.0862234,0.5, 0}, {20, 2.15164, 0, 0.377913, 0.5, 0}, {20, 6.43098, 0, 0.0116446, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.88699, 1, 0.927266, 0.5, 0}, {20, 3.10361, 0, 0.543757, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.96474, 1, 0.479332, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.86771, 0, 0.245349, 0.5, 0}, {20, 7.12694, 1, 0.759896, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.70262, 1, 0.984993, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.54488, 1, 0.217045, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.75599, 1, 0.459017, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.24446, 1, 0.884729, 0.5, 0}, {20, 1.81927, 1, 0.583854, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.45835, 0, 0.263973, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.80958, 1, 0.91956, 0.5, 0}, {20, 2.96297, 1, 0.423835, 0.5, 0}, {20, 8.2311, 1, 0.98729, 0.5, 0}, {20, 5.76275, 1, 0.587943, 0.5, 0}}};
```

Comment: Try `newcoloredData = Style[Point[{#1, #2}], <the rest of your code in the original coloredData>]`, then pass that to `Graphics`. Note the addition of `Point` inside `Style`.

Comment: This comment worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend generating a list of `Point` objects encapsulated in `Style` directives to feed to `Graphics`:

```
newcoloredData = 
  Style[
    Point[{#1, #2}], 
    {#3, #6} /. {{0, 0} -> Gray, {0, 1} -> Black, {1, 0} -> Red}
  ]& @@@ Flatten[data, 1];

Graphics[{coloredData}, Axes -> True]
```

[image: graphics result]

Note also that, rather than `Flatten`ing your data all the way, then re-`Partition`ing it, you can specify a level in `Flatten` to obtain the same result.

---

If you have to do the color conversion on a lot of points, the following might be faster than the `ReplaceAll` approach:

```
coloredData2 = 
  Style[
    Point[{#1, #2}], 
    {Gray, Black, Red}[[FromDigits[{#3, #6}, 2] + 1]]
  ]& @@@ Flatten[data, 1];

coloredData2 == newcoloredData         (* Out: True *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, it worked great! Really appreciate it

Comment: @JomyBlue You are very welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`VertexColors`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexColors.html) to style a list of points.

Using your `coloredData` as input:

```
pointListWithVertexColors = Point[#, VertexColors -> #2] & @@ 
    Transpose[coloredData /. Style -> List];

Graphics[pointListWithVertexColors, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Using `data` as input we can do:

```
pointListWithVertexColors2 = Point[#, VertexColors -> #2] & @@ 
  Transpose[{{#, #2},  {#3, #6} /.
    {{0, 0} -> Gray, {0, 1} -> Black, {1, 0} -> Red}} & @@@ (Join @@ data)]

pointListWithVertexColors == pointListWithVertexColors2
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, using the efficient `GraphicsComplex`:

```
Graphics[
 GraphicsComplex[
  Flatten[N@data[[All, All, {1, 2}]], 1],
  Point[
   Range@Length@data,
   VertexColors -> Flatten[
     data[[All, All, {3, 6}]] /. {{0, 0} -> Gray, {0, 1} -> Black, {1, 0} -> Red},
     1]]
  ]
 ]
```